# Filtrar informações do dia atual laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variáveis, filter

Tenho a seguinte variável na minha `View`:

```
Auth::user()
    ->LogsSearch()
    ->where('base', $linha->sigla)
    ->where('created_at', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->count()
```

e desejo filtrar os resultados do dia de hoje, percebi que o problema é no filtro estou filtrando somente a data de hoje `date('Y-m-d')` e no `created_at` é **2019-05-05 13:17:08**, como faço para ignorar o horário do `created_at` e filtrar só pela data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Eloquent existe o método `whereDate` que considerará apenas a data da respectiva coluna:

```
Auth::user()->LogsSearch()
    ->whereDate('created_at', date('Y-m-d'));
```

Assim como possui `whereMonth`, para apenas o mês, `whereDay`, apenas para o dia, `whereYear`, apenas para o ano, e `whereTime`, apenas para o horário.

- [Eloquent: Where Clauses / Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente !

Answer (score -2):

Olá, boa tarde,

Você pode usar o carbon, que por padrão já vem embutido no laravel, ou você pode usar o strtotime.

**STRTOME é mais recomendável para algo tão simples como esse.**

```
$data = Auth::user()->LogsSearch()
->where('base', $linha->sigla)->where('created_at', date('Y-m-d'))->count()
$time = strtotime($data);
```

Agora você pode testar em sua view, basta passar a variável para ver a mágica acontecer.
Agora se você quiser usar o Carbon, você pode simplesmente usar o seguinte código:

```
$data = Auth::user()->LogsSearch()
->where('base', $linha->sigla)->where('created_at', date('Y-m-d'))->count()
$time = strtotime($data);
$minhaData = Carbon::createFromDate($data);
```

Não esqueça de importar o seu Carbon.

Comment: No que muda na cláusula `where` ao usar a função `strtotime` ou `Carbon`? Principalmente porque em ambos os exemplos você manteve o valor de `date` dentro do `where`.